# What does "source" the bin/activate script mean?

Tags: bash, shell

This is in reference to a response I received that said I need to source this script in order to active the virtualenv.

No idea what that means, beginner here trying to figure out virtualenv.

Comment: http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Source_command

Comment: The [`virtualenvwrapper` script](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) makes working with virtual environments a lot easier. Instead of `source /my_project/bin/activate`, you do `workon my_project`.

Comment: Excellent question, I have wondered that myself, too!

Answer (score 20):

To source a script is to run it in the context of the current shell rather than running it in a new shell.

For example:

```
. myscript.sh
```

or:

```
source myscript.sh
```

(depending on which shell you're running).

If you run the script in its own shell, any changes it makes to the environment are in *that* shell rather than the one you call it from. By sourcing it, you can affect the environment of the current shell.

For example, examine the following transcript:

```
pax> cat script.sh 
export xyzzy=plugh
echo $xyzzy

pax> export xyzzy=twisty

pax> echo $xyzzy ; script.sh ; echo $xyzzy
twisty
plugh
twisty

pax> echo $xyzzy ; . script.sh ; echo $xyzzy
twisty
plugh
plugh
```

When you *run* the script (different shell), it sets `xyzzy` to `plugh` but that gets lost when the shell exits back to your original shell. You'll find the original value has been "restored" (in quotes because the original value was never actually changed, only a copy of it was).

When you *source* it, it's just as if you typed the commands within the current shell so the effect on the variables is persistent.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `source` is a bashism; so this pattern is not really portable.

Comment: @Burhan, added that, though it depends on your definition of "portable". I think it's been nearly a decade since I've touched a machine without `bash` :-)